# Displaying Objects: puts and p, to_s and inspect

Tags: ruby, methods, overriding

On the Rubymonk website tutorial I am stuck on an interactive question (2.3 Displaying Objects: puts and p, to_s and inspect) on the inspect vs to_s portion.They ask to override to_s method >'so that it returns a string with both the item's name and quantity.'

Here is the link to the specific question: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/108-displaying-objects

I am not sure how to approach this portion. I did skip around this tutorial, so I might have missed how to approach a similar problem that may have shown how to tackle this question.

I utilized a puts method and interpolation of an expression within a string:

```
class Item
   def initialize(item_name, qty)
     @item_name = item_name
     @qty = qty
   end

   def to_s
      puts '#{@item_name} and #{@qty}'
   end
 end

item = Item.new("a",1)

puts item
p item
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def to_s
  p "#{@item_name} and #{@qty}"
end
```

with double quotes and p

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Single quoted strings don't interpolate, only double quoted strings do
2. You are not returning the string, you are passing the string as an argument to `puts` and return the result of `puts`, however, if you look at the documentation for `puts`, you will see it always returns `nil`

So, your code should be something like

```
class Item
  def initialize(item_name, qty)
    @item_name = item_name
    @qty = qty
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@item_name} and #{@qty}"
  end
end

item = Item.new('a', 1)

puts item
p item
```

Comment: Works. Thank you for the detailed tips. 1) I never knew that there was a difference between 1 and 2 quotation marks, so thank you for that. 2) I just copied that portion about returning a string from the actual question itself, but I will definitely keep your tip in mind. Also what is the documentation portion you were talking about? Thank you in advance, much appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation for `Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) says `puts(obj, …) → nil`, i.e. `puts` takes one or more arguments and returns `nil`. But [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s) shouldn't return `nil`, it should return a `String` (that's why it is *called* "to string", after all)!